# Android : LongClickListener not working

Tags: android

I don't know whay when i setting longClickListener to my a view , it is not fire,It is my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="16"
        android:id="@+id/zoom_level"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/zoom_in_bg"
            android:layout_above="@+id/zoom_out"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/zoom_in"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ImageView
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/zoom_out_bg"
            android:id="@+id/zoom_out"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_remove_black_24dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and it is fragment

```
 public class MapFragment extends BaseFragment implements View.OnLongClickListener
{

    private View rootView;
    private org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView mapView ;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation, container, false);
        mapView = new org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView(getContext());
        mapView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        relativeLayout.addView(mapView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view)
    {
        KLog.error("Long Click called");

        return true;
    }
}
```

i have tried `SetClickable(true)` , `setLongClickable(true)`, `setFocusable(true)` but i cannot solve this problem.what is the solution?
please advise

Answer (score 1):

You can add this code to your class:

```
mapView.setLongClickable(true);
```

Or add `android:longClickable="true"` to xml.

Comment: Can you make sure you click is mapView?Mapview may not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Put android:longClickable="true" in your Relative layout where you want to add onLongClickListener:

```
   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:longClickable="true">


   </RelativeLayout>
```

Try with set long click listener on Relative layout instead of mapView:

```
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);
    relativeLayout.setOnLongClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Try with setting listener on relativeLayout. See my updated answer.